# strip HTML from a textarea submitted by user

Tags: html

I am using a plugin called "user submitted posts" - there is a text area which allows user to input the content 
here is the code :

```
<li class="usp_content">
            <label for="user-submitted-content" class="usp_label">Your Content</label>
            <div>
                <textarea class="usp_textarea" name="user-submitted-content" id="user-submitted-content" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
```

the problem is that this code allows user to input HTML code , like  and etc. I tried to strip it from HTML but I just cant figure out how , searched and tried so many codes and it does not work.

I really appreciate if someone tells me how to strip the html from above code so the person cant put html

Comment: what is the code that you have tried so far

Comment: So you're saying the input allows for HTML code and you don't want that? You're going to have to take what's in the user-submitted-content textarea and edit it.

Comment: You need to use a regular expression to strip out html characters. This can be done with JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: @RJHill yes, this code allows user to input HTML - I dont want them to be able to input HTML in the text area

Comment: @Satya I tried this code : `function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
jQuery('#textareaid').text(function(index, old){
 return strip(old);
});` but it did not work

Comment: @Dave I'm going to have to agree with suhas, regex would be the best way to go here, seeing as how you can just strip out any text that is found to be inside of '<' and '>'.

Comment: @suhaskhot can you please tell me how to do it with php ?

Comment: @Dave here's a great writeup of regex, it will only benefit you later if you learn it. http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php

Comment: You need to sanitize the input before inserting it into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You must write something like this

```
<?php
    $yourTextareaContent = $_POST['user-submitted-content']; // if form METHOD="POST"
    //$yourTextareaContent = $_GET['user-submitted-content']; // if form METHOD="GET"
    echo strip_tags($yourTextareaContent);
?>
```

Also you have to do it on the server side (php script which receive content from your form).

Comment: I agree. This seems to be the best solution thus far.

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP then you could strip html tags using:

```
echo strip_tags($yourTextareaContent);
```

See: [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: can you please put this code inside what I have ? I am a php self educated and in basic level, thank you

Comment: I tried this but got an error  `<?php echo strip_tags(<textarea class="usp_textarea" name="user-submitted-content" id="user-submitted-content" rows="5"></textarea>); ?>`